# Hide Group Instance lines

Tags: groups

Someone said, group instances are rendered faster, so I've decided to replace actual bolt objects with group instances. Though, my model turned into a hairy mess, that I can't see through. Yes, it disappears, when you turn active "Only Render", but I need to work with it!

[image: Hairy mess]

Comment: Thank you! Selecting all by type "Empty", going to Empty tab in Properties window and setting size to 0 with holding Alt helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting all by type "Empty", going to Empty tab in Properties window and setting size to 0 with holding Alt helped.